# QGIS join by location not returning for features

Tags: qgis, census, spatial-join

I have eight contours/features in one shapefile (contour.shp) that i want to find the number of population within each contour, this is in another shp.

I am using join attributes by location to do the population counts, both shp's have the same CRS.

The results are fine for all but one of the contours/features. For that that contour a feature is not returned at all in the exported shapefile (not even a null), leaving only seven contours/features with counts.

I really need the counts in that 8th contours/feature, is this a problem with input shapefile (contour.shp)? if so what can solve the problem?

`Keep all records` was selected. The shapefile is polygon (I think). What are the implications either way.

Comment: Did you enable the **Keep all records** option? I always use this as it ignores intersecting features.

Comment: Is your contour.shp lines or polygons?